# Query MongoDB N-Tier Nested on every Level

Tags: mongodb, nested

I've got this structure of document, saved in MongoDB 2.6.1, running on Linux:

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "name" : "Level0",
    "childs" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "name" : "Level1",
            "childs" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : "3",
                    "name" : "Level2",
                    "childs" : [ 
                        {
                            "id" : "4",
                            "name" : "Level3-1",
                        }, 
                        {
                            "id" : "5",
                            "name" : "Level3-2",
                        }
                    ]
                }
...
```

Every Element got his childs and every child-element got his own childs until the technical end.

Now I want to Query my MongoDB with something like:

```
db.categories.find({'childs':{$elemMatch:{$all:['Level19-23']}}})
```

This Query dont work by the way.

What is a good query to get my elements?

I dont know anything about the children or parents, I've got only the name of the element, and I need the element with all his children.

Anyone got an advise for me, the MongoDB Newbe? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked into hierarchical data storage? http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/category-hierarchy/
Instead of nesting the elements, you could store them as separate documents, but store the children id's in parent documents. This made it easier for me to query the data.

Comment: Hey acheaito, I will give it a try to save my data like this! :) Thank you.